# static template function specialization for return values

Tags: c++, templates

This is what I want to achieve for the end user:

```
auto spherePos = Primitive::createSphere<VertexPosition>();
auto spherePosNormTex = Primitive::createSphere<VertexPositionNormalTexture>();
```

Basically I want the end user to define what kind of vertex type he wants for his primitive by passing the the vertex type as a parameter.

I have a templated Mesh class like this:

```
template<typename VertexType>
class Mesh
{
    std::vector<VertexType> _vertices;
    ...
}
```

and i want the functions above to return a Mesh according to the template parameter that was passed to the function.

but im having a hard time building those functions, this is what i've been trying:

```
class Primitive
{
    template<typename VertexType>
    static Mesh<VertexType> createSphere();

    // specialization for the position only sphere
    template<>
    static Mesh<VertexPosition> createSphere<VertexPosition>(){ ... }
}
```

but this gives me: "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope", so i tried the struct specialization way:

```
class Primitive
{
    template<typename VertexType>
    struct Sphere
    {
        static Mesh<VertexType> create();
    }

    template<>
    struct Sphere<VertexPosition>
    {
        static Mesh<Position> create(){ ... }
    }

    template<typename T>
    static Mesh<T> createSphere(){ return Sphere<T>::create(); }
}
```

But this again gives me the same error: "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope", both ways using gcc 4.8

Is there something I'm missing? is there another way I should be doing this?
I know I could some kind of flag parameter on the functions, but I think the template way would look cleaner for the end user.

Comment: Don't specialize your members; *overload* them. Unfortunately, yours have no parameters, so that isn't going to happen easily, as differing by return-type only isn't enough. (and all your structs need tail-semi-colons, btw).

Comment: thanks. yeah i thought about overloading them, but since i don't have any parameters its hard. i could start naming the functions as "createSpherePosition()" "createSpherePositionNormal()" but somehow i think it look uglier than what im trying to achieve (specialization of return types). as for the semi-colons, classes are missing them too, i wrote this in a hurry :p

Comment: +1 to the question, btw. Contains everything an SO question should, what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, and what your observations of both are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specializing member functions is fine. However, in order to do so you can't do it directly in the class. Try

```
class Primitive
{
public:
    template<typename VertexType>
    static Mesh<VertexType> createSphere();
};

// specialization for the position only sphere
template<>
Mesh<VertexPosition> Primitive::createSphere<VertexPosition>(){ return Mesh<VertexPosition>(); }
```

Comment: +1 this should work. I was so hung up on the second implementation I didn't even scroll back up to the original problem. nice job!